# How to copy a structure containing a pointer from user space to kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

Here is the structure I get :

```
struct my_struct {
    int size;
    int *buffer;
};
```

Now, I want to copy a variable from user space to kernel space using `copy_from_user` but it does not seem to work. 
What I do is this:

In user space I declare a variable `struct my_struct data` which I in initialize and pass it onto an ioctl, and in the kernel I call `copy_from_user(&mydataInkernel, arg, sizeof(mydataInkernel))` after which I allocate the right memory for the pointer and call again `copy_from_user(mydataInkernel.buffer, arg + 4, mydataInkernel.size)`. I don't know what I am doing wrong but it is not working.

Does the first copy also copy all the data pointed to by mydataInkernel.buffer ?

Is there a way to do this simply using `copy_from_user` ?

**UPDATE 1:**
For the size of a pointer on my architecture, it is indeed 8 bytes (x86_64). To be more clear I'm writing a device driver and this is for the need to get a data from the user space to kernel space using an ioctl. So here is the code I try to do to get the buffer:

```
     ret_val = copy_from_user(dma_info, (ioctl_dma *)arg, sizeof(dma_info));
     if (ret_val)
           printk(KERN_WARNING "COPY_FROM_USER failed !");
     else
           ret_val = copy_from_user(dma_info->buffer, (ioctl_dma *)arg->buffer, dma_info->taille);

     if (ret_val)
            printk(KERN_WARNING "COPY_FROM_USER failed !");
     else
     {
       //Do the treatment
     }
```

And here is the prototype of the ioctl function:

```
long    pci_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

So I don't think my second copy_from_user is correct even after the cast.

Nb: dma_info is of type the struct defined above.

Answer (score 3):

if you have the initial struct copied in, why can't you just copy_from(arg->buffer, ....) instead of playing games like arg + 4?

since no code was shown it is hard to say for sure, but most likely the problem is in the above. offset of 'buffer' *is not* 4 bytes. It is 8 due to alignment requirements, assuming x86_64.

to make it clear:

1. copy from to a local object
2. validate that the buffer sizes looks sane (e.g. it's not megabytes in size when you expect only kilobytes)
3. create *another* local object. allocate enough memory for the buffer and assign to the local object
4. take the address of the buffer from the copy made in step one (e.g. localobj->buffer) and copyfrom that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've updated the question. I hope it gives more information now.